# Convert string type of categories to integer type

Tags: python

I want to convert a vector of string type categories into integer type. For example for Fisher's Iris data that contain three categories (i.e., setosa, versicolor and versicolor), I convert the categories into different integers such as 0, 1 and 2 corresponding to the three class labels for classification modeling. In addition to self defining a conversion function, are there some specialized functions (of some machine learning packages) to do so?

Comment: Take a look at [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
>>> labl = "setosa, versicolor, versicolors"
>>> labl = labl.split(",")
>>> LabelEncoder().fit_transform(labl)
array([2, 0, 1])
```